# I'm getting a wrong expectedTravelTime from MKRoute

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to calculate the expectedTravelTime in my app, but I get different values when compared to GoogleMaps.

Here is my code:

```
NSArray *startLocationArray = [startLocation componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSArray *destinationArray = [destination componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

MKPlacemark *placemarkStartLocation = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([startLocationArray[0] intValue],
                                                                                            [startLocationArray[1] intValue]) addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItemStartLocation = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkStartLocation];

MKPlacemark *placemarkDestination = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([destinationArray[0] intValue],
                                                                                            [destinationArray[1] intValue]) addressDictionary:nil];
MKMapItem *mapItemDestination = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemarkDestination];

MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
[request setSource:mapItemStartLocation];
[request setDestination:mapItemDestination];
[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile];
[request setRequestsAlternateRoutes:NO];
MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:request];
__block MKRoute *route;

[directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
    if ( ! error && [response routes] > 0)
    {
        route = [[response routes] objectAtIndex:0];

        double exceedingTime = fmod(route.expectedTravelTime, 60);
        eta = (route.expectedTravelTime - exceedingTime)/60;
        int iEta = (int)eta;

        lblEta.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%im", iEta, nil];
    }
}];
```

startLocation and destination are passed outside the method, and their values are:

```
startLocation = 37.776402,-122.408470
destination = 37.831287,-122.485519
```

I get:

```
route.distance = 1513 (meters)
route.expectedTravelTime = 491 (should be seconds, so finally 8 minutes)
```

but on GoogleMaps I get more than 30 minutes of expectedTravelTime and more than 9 miles of
distance

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems are these conversions which use `intValue` instead of `doubleValue`:

```
[startLocationArray[0] intValue], [startLocationArray[1] intValue]

[destinationArray[0] intValue], [destinationArray[1] intValue]
```

The start and destination coordinates have a fractional part (e.g. `37.776402`) and so you must use `doubleValue` (which matches the defined types of latitude and longitude in the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` struct).

Using `intValue`, the code is getting the route from `37, -122` to `37, -122` which is a short trip inside a golf course in Santa Cruz, CA.

Change `intValue` in the above lines to `doubleValue`.